# .NET watch exclude files does not compile

Tags: .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-core, msbuild

I have a .NET blazor project where I want to use dotnet watch. The blazor project is in a library, not an executable. I run watch on the executable project. In this project I try to exclude all files in wwwroot from triggering a rebuild. Include was required according to error message, so I added an empty one. Here is the msbuild part.

```xml
  <ItemGroup>
    <Watch Include="" Exclude="wwwroot\**\*" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

And when building the project I get this error, as if Exclude is not supported. But documentation states this is how to exclude files from [dotnet watch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/dotnet-watch?view=aspnetcore-5.0#customize-files-list-to-watch).

```
> dotnet build
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.8.0+126527ff1 for .NET
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Determining projects to restore...
<proj>.csproj(51,23): error MSB4066: The attribute "Exclude" in element <Watch> is unrecognized.

Build FAILED.
```

Are there some changes in .NET 5.0 regarding Watch? Do I need to add something else in the csproj to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **Watch** include item cannot be empty and this is an xml syntax error.

**Instead**, you should use this:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Watch Remove="wwwroot\**\*" />
 </ItemGroup>
```

**And** then use `dotnet watch build` command.

**By default**, the **Watch** item will not monitor any `js` files, `css` files and will only watch `.cs`,`.csproj`,`.resx` files.

**Note**: if you want to exclude `.cs`, `.resx` files, you cannot use **Remove** and you should add `Watch="false"` for file to exclude them. Check [this tip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/dotnet-watch?view=aspnetcore-5.0#customize-files-list-to-watch).

[image]

And if you have extended the Watch Range by your need, basically, add your other custom files, you should pay attention to the below:

===============================================================

**In fact**, since the `include` cannot be empty and `exclude` should work with `include` at the same time. If you already include the files before, and then use `include` with `exclude` to remove some files, it is wrong because you have include some files twice. The `exclude` node acts on the current `include` node. And if the above xml node still have the same `item include`, the file always exists under that item.

**Either**, when you use a wide range of files for `watch include`, exclude some files that do not need to be monitored at the same time.

Like: `<Watch Include="**\*.js;**\*.css" Exclude="wwwroot\**\*">` to remove the js and css files under `wwwroot` folder. When you first extend the files into Watch, you should remove the related files based on your need at the same time.

**And** I think you want to exclude some js files(not the default watch files) and other non-default monitored file, in this case, the best way is to use **Remove**.

**In other word**, `Remove` and `Include` works for other extended non-default files while `Watch="false"` works for default watched files.

Comment: Makes sense when you say it :). I found that I couldn't use an empty Include, and sort of realized this.

Comment: The root cause seemed to be that I included typescript msbuild task which builds all .ts files into .js+.js.map, and default settings did this for every build, even unchanged files so dotnet-watch entered a loop of compiling. But this also means that .js and .js.map files are added to watch by default. So I'm not sure what you mean by default file types. Is <Watch> an msbuild feature used by asp.net watch command?

Comment: Someone (not my csproj) is adding .js and .map to watch and I needed to get rid of them. But I solved it by fixing typescript msbuild task to run in incremental mode, which seem to be "normal" in that it doesn't rebuild always, only changed files.

Comment: I am curious the difference between your solution `<Watch Remove="..." />` and [official way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/dotnet-watch?view=aspnetcore-6.0#opt-out-of-files-to-be-watched) `<Compile Include="..." Watch="false" />`

Answer (score 2):

On MacOS, the accepted answer:

```
 <ItemGroup>
    <Watch Remove="wwwroot\**\*" />
 </ItemGroup>
```

Does not seem to work; however, I was able to ignore the `wwwroot` directory using:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Update="wwwroot/**/*" Watch="false" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Source: [Opt-out of files to be watched - Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/dotnet-watch?view=aspnetcore-5.0#opt-out-of-files-to-be-watched)